# How to Remove Hyperlink from Items in a List (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: list, web-part, links

I have a couple of connected `webparts` that are `lists`. When the filtered results are returned in one `webpart`, there is a column where each item in the `list` is linked, where you can click on it and read that item's properties.

I want to remove that hyperlink. I read how to do it in SPD for SP2010, but I'm not good at raw HTML and can't figure it out in SPD2013.

If there is a way to completely remove the links without SPD, that would be my preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Web Part properties

1. Change current view
2. Uncheck the column `title linked to item` or `title linked to edit menu`
3. Select `title`, it would just say title

No need for SPD or any customization.

Comment: @Razor7Tech it happens to all of us:)

Comment: @Razor7Tech.. if answer helped you, please mark it as answered. Thanks:)